# EOS Voice Chat Missing include

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I hope you are all doing well. I’m currently working on this video: https://youtu.be/HYnZAX7g0lc It’s about the voice chat function with EOS. I’ve installed the EOS voice chat plugin and have also followed the three previous videos from the tutorial series. Right at this point (Link directly to this timestamp: https://youtu.be/HYnZAX7g0lc?t=292), he added the dependency for the EOS Voice-Plugin. Then, a bit later at this point (Link: https://youtu.be/HYnZAX7g0lc?t=308), when he does the include, I can’t find the include. Does it work for you? Can anyone help me?
I would be grateful for any assistance.